# Database Design Feedback on How to Model Entities with Multiple Dependent Attributes

Tags: database-design

The issue is representing two unique entities, reports and projects, where the projects will have a type of findings based on the project type and also be unique for a given instance. So...

Reports can have multiple projects and projects can have multiple reports.

Projects are of unique types and are entities themselves. They can have several types of findings that are unique to their project type. They're also unique in a given instance based on a date value. So a project may exist over multiple reports, but it's findings will be different and unique for each of those instances. In other words a Projects findings will only ever apply to that instance, always unique and never used again.

Example

- Report A has Projects 1 and Projects 2.
- Project 1 has type X with Mixed and Quantitative results.
- Project 2 has type Y with Mixed and Quantitative results.

Project 1's `Mixed` and `Quantitative` results are unique to type X Project 2's `Mixed` and `Quantitative` results are unique to type Y.

Here is a very basic ERD I made up that's the current design.

[image]

Comment: You only need to have have a single `program_type` type table with a column that identifies whether it's `1` or `2`. Then depending on your data types, you could consolidate your results tables.

Comment: The results tables are unique though, while they're the same "methods" the fields are different depending on whether it's program type one or two. So The results tables depend on the program type.

Comment: Right, so you identify each table with a column of the program number.

Comment: Alright, I appreciate your help. I am trying to understand you here. So, in stead of having a table for each program_type I just have one table where the type is an attribute in a field for program_type? The issue I see there is that there are additional attributes unique to the program_type, so I would have null values when a program_type did not have certain attributes.

Comment: I would have to get a better understanding of your relationships. You are duplicating data by having "two" program type tables. You only need one and an identifier (1 or 2).

Comment: I understand that take, but I have the "two" program tables because if it's program_type_one then it will have unique attributes for that program type not shared with program_type_two and vice versa. In addition, program_type_one can only have program_type_one_results, if they shared it would be possible to have program_type_two_results.